# How could I convert Binary into Decimal using recursive way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I basically finished everything..
I just can't find a way to multiply each integer by 2^0, 2^1 ... and so on
Here is my code

```
def BinaryToDecimal(binaryString):
    if len(binaryString) == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return int(binaryString[-1:])*(2**(4-len(binaryString))) + BinaryToDecimal(binaryString[:len(binaryString)-1])
```

If I have input '1000', I return last digit of the string and do recursion by eliminating the last digit so, '1000' --> '100' --> '10' and so on

The problem here is that I just cannot find a way to multiply last digit by its corresponding power of 2. Any thought of how to get 0,1,2,3 when length of binary string is 4,3,2,1 ?

Comment: By the way, you could just `return int(binaryString, 2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making this more complicated than it needs to be. No power calculation is required.

```
def binary_to_decimal(bstring):
    if not bstring:
        return 0
    return binary_to_decimal(bstring[:-1]) * 2 + int(bstring[-1])

# Test

for i in range(16):
    b = format(i, 'b')
    n = binary_to_decimal(b)
    print('{:2} {:4} -> {}'.format(i, b, n))
```

**output**

```
 0 0    -> 0
 1 1    -> 1
 2 10   -> 2
 3 11   -> 3
 4 100  -> 4
 5 101  -> 5
 6 110  -> 6
 7 111  -> 7
 8 1000 -> 8
 9 1001 -> 9
10 1010 -> 10
11 1011 -> 11
12 1100 -> 12
13 1101 -> 13
14 1110 -> 14
15 1111 -> 15
```

This function also handles leading zeros correctly:

```
for i in range(16):
    b = format(i, '05b')
    n = binary_to_decimal(b)
    print('{:2} {} -> {}'.format(i, b, n))
```

**output**

```
 0 00000 -> 0
 1 00001 -> 1
 2 00010 -> 2
 3 00011 -> 3
 4 00100 -> 4
 5 00101 -> 5
 6 00110 -> 6
 7 00111 -> 7
 8 01000 -> 8
 9 01001 -> 9
10 01010 -> 10
11 01011 -> 11
12 01100 -> 12
13 01101 -> 13
14 01110 -> 14
15 01111 -> 15
```

---

Actually, we don't even need that `int` call, if we assume we only get passed valid strings:

```
def binary_to_decimal(bstring):
    if not bstring:
        return 0
    return binary_to_decimal(bstring[:-1]) * 2 + (bstring[-1] == '1')
```

Comment: Oh wow... It is much easier and simpler using this way, Thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to recursively parse a number (as an exercise) then have a look at this:

```
def parse_binary(binary_string, power):
    if len(binary_string) == 0:
        return 0
    last_digit = int(binary_string[-1]) * (2**power)
    return last_digit + parse_binary(binary_string[:-1], power+1)

def BinaryToDecimal(binary_string):
    return parse_binary(binary_string, 0)
```

But if you want to do this efficiently then simply call `int(binary_string, 2)`.

Comment: You could default `power = 0`, then the parameter doesn't need passed

Comment: @cricket_007 But it's still there. That's a proper wrapping.