# Program to convert decimal to binary and binary to decimal?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am meant to write a program that will convert a decimal to a binary and then another that will do the opposite. I know there are python functions to do this, but I think we are meant to do it the longer way. The pseudocode goes like this:

Decimal to Binary:

```
number = Prompt user for input, convert to int

Set quotient equal to number, remainder equal to zero

while(number!=0)

     (quotient,remainder)=divmod(quotient,2)

     print(remainder)
```

Binary to Decimal

```
number=Prompt user for input

Get string length of number = n

for x in range(n)

   sum+=(2^n) times x

print sum
```

Any help?

Comment: In answer to your actual question, no. Writing your code for you is not help. Especially when you can't be bothered to format your question properly.

Comment: And where is your problem exactly? If output is wrong, pls post that in the question, with its input.

Answer (score 1):

Codes for manually converting. Am using loops here. It can be done using recursion too.

```
#Binary to Decimal
def btod(binary):
    decimal = 0 
    for digit in binary: 
        decimal = decimal*2 + int(digit) 

    return decimal

#Decimal to Binary
def dtob(decimal):
    if decimal == 0:
        return 0

    binary=''
    decimal = int(decimal)          #incase arg is int
    while (decimal > 0):
        binary+= str(decimal%2)
        decimal = int(decimal/2)

    return binary[::-1]     #reverse the string


print(btod('101'))
#5

print(dtob('5'))
#101
```

Comment: How would you do this with recursion?

Comment: How would you do this with recursion?

Comment: [Python Program to Convert Decimal to Binary Using Recursion](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/examples/decimal-binary-recursion)

Comment: [How could I convert Binary into Decimal using recursive way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40567667/how-could-i-convert-binary-into-decimal-using-recursive-way)

Answer (score 0):

**The translation dictionary for your pseudo-code:**

"Prompt user for input, convert to int":

```
int(input("Enter a decimal number: "))
```

"Set quotient equal to number, remainder equal to zero":

```
quotient = number
remainder = 0
```

"divmod(quotient,2)":

```
quotient // 2, quotient % 2
```

---

"Prompt user for input":

```
input("Enter a binary number: ")
```

"Get string length of number = n":

```
n = len(number)
```

"(2^n) times x":

```
2**n * x
```

"print sum":

```
print(sum)
```

---

Use this dictionary for *replacing the corresponding parts in your pseudo-code*. All other parts *keep in their place*, including indentations.

**Note:**
By your pseudo-code your program "Decimal to Binary" will print the converted decimal number in the *column* - read the result *from bottom to top*.